# Can't get Spring Insight to monitor my application

Tags: spring-insight

I have installed Spring Tool Suite along with tc Server and couldn't manage to get Spring Insight to show my application. I have successfully added my web application through servers tab and started it without any exceptions. I have also played around a bit with the application so that Spring Insight can catch the activities. In server properties' Insight tab "Enable gathering of metrics" is selected and I can see my application under modules tab aswell.

I can access my project through mysite:8080/myProject page and Insight through mysite:8080/insight but Spring Insight page doesn't show my application.

I'm using Spring Tools Suite 3.0.0.RELEASE bundled with tc Server v2.7.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my simplified startup log:

```
    Eki 02, 2012 9:41:05 AM com.springsource.insight.tcserver.WeavingHelper findRepositoriesForClassPath
INFO: file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-collection-1.8.3.RELEASE.jar: aspects will be woven into the main Tomcat classloader
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:05 AM com.springsource.insight.tcserver.WeavingHelper findRepositoriesForClassPath
INFO: file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-plugin-jdbc-1.8.3.RELEASE.jar: aspects will be woven into the main Tomcat classloader
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:05 AM com.springsource.insight.tcserver.WeavingHelper findRepositoriesForClassPath
INFO: file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/insight/collection-plugins/insight-plugin-tomcat-1.8.3.RELEASE.jar: aspects will be woven into the main Tomcat classloader
ASPECTJ: aspectj.overweaving=true: overweaving switched ON
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:07 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:07 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 774 ms
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 796 ms
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 4213 ms
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: VMware vFabric tc Runtime 2.7.1.RELEASE/7.0.29.A.RELEASE
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\Claimer.UI.xml
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.SetContextPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Claimer.UI' did not find a matching property.
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:12 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\Claimer.UI\WEB-INF\lib\el-api-2.2.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext addApplicationListener
INFO: The listener "com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener" is already configured for this context. The duplicate definition has been ignored.
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:42 AM com.springsource.insight.collection.strategies.CollectionStrategyRunner enable
INFO: Enabled Strategy com.springsource.insight.collection.strategies.EndPointOnlyCollectionStrategy@ee68cd7c
Eki 02, 2012 9:41:42 AM com.springsource.insight.collection.strategies.CollectionStrategyRunner enable
INFO: Enabled Strategy com.springsource.insight.collection.strategies.PrefixExcludeCollectionStrategy@d813cb8b
09:41:42,445 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:41:42,447 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:41:42,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/lib/Alias-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
09:41:42,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@15ff6c16 - Will scan for changes in file [C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\Claimer.UI\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml] every 60 seconds. 
09:41:42,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
09:41:42,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:41:42,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
09:41:42,900 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:41:43,518 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:41:43,518 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUTWARN]
09:41:43,543 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to OFF
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to INFO
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework]
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.compugroup] to INFO
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.compugroup]
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf] to INFO
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.cxf]
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf.interceptor] to INFO
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.cxf.interceptor]
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.

Eki 02, 2012 9:41:43 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
09:41:42,445 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
09:41:42,447 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
09:41:42,448 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml]
09:41:42,452 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/lib/Alias-1.2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar!/logback.xml]
09:41:42,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.turbo.ReconfigureOnChangeFilter@15ff6c16 - Will scan for changes in file [C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\wtpwebapps\Claimer.UI\WEB-INF\classes\logback.xml] every 60 seconds. 
09:41:42,769 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
09:41:42,780 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:41:42,811 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUT]
09:41:42,900 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:41:43,518 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
09:41:43,518 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [STDOUTWARN]
09:41:43,543 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LevelAction - ROOT level set to OFF
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.springframework] to INFO
09:41:43,545 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.springframework]
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [com.compugroup] to INFO
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[com.compugroup]
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf] to INFO
09:41:43,551 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.cxf]
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [org.apache.cxf.interceptor] to INFO
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [STDOUT] to Logger[org.apache.cxf.interceptor]
09:41:43,552 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.

09:41:43.596 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
09:41:43.875 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Tue Oct 02 09:41:43 EEST 2012]; root of context hierarchy
09:41:44.294 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from URL [file:/C:/Users/osahin/Downloads/springsource/vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE/spring-insight-instance/wtpwebapps/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/classes/web-appl-context.xml]
09:41:44.538 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml]
09:41:44.649 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [ws-anadolu-context.xml]
09:41:49.164 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@63d63048: defining beans [cxf,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusWiringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.Jsr250BeanPostProcessor,org.apache.cxf.bus.spring.BusExtensionPostProcessor,serviceClient,*.http-conduit,user.proxyFactory,user,saglikKurumu.proxyFactory,saglikKurumu,odemeKurumu.proxyFactory,odemeKurumu,webinterface.proxyFactory,webinterface,infrastructure.proxyFactory,infrastructure,rawObject.proxyFactory,rawObject,propertyConfigurer]; root of factory hierarchy
09:41:51.742 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://wsdl.hastane.claimer.compugroup.com}ClaimerHastaneWsdlService from class com.compugroup.claimer.hastane.wsdl.ClaimerHastaneWsdl
09:41:56.478 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://sigortaserver.claimer.compugroup.com}ClaimerSigortaServerWsdlService from class com.compugroup.claimer.sigortaserver.ClaimerSigortaServerWsdl
09:41:59.023 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://webinterface.claimer.compugroup.com}WebInterfaceWsdlService from class com.compugroup.claimer.webinterface.WebInterfaceWsdl
09:42:00.939 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://infrastructure.claimer.compugroup.com}UserServiceService from class com.compugroup.claimer.infrastructure.service.UserService
09:42:02.732 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean - Creating Service {http://infrastructure.claimer.compugroup.com}ClaimerInfrastructureServiceService from class com.compugroup.claimer.infrastructure.wsdl.ClaimerInfrastructureService
09:42:05.754 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 22144 ms
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:06 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialized
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.0.6 (FCS FCS) for context '/Claimer.UI'
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:09 AM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstance
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.NotNull, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Size, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Pattern, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Min, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.Max, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.javascript.ClientServiceConfigParser parse
WARNING: Found JavaScript function definition for class javax.validation.constraints.AssertFalse, but that class is not presented
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.cache.CacheManager getCacheFactory
INFO: Selected fallback cache factory
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache
INFO: Creating LRUMap cache instance using parameters: {com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews=1, com.sun.faces.expressionFactory=com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl, sigorta=anadolu, com.sun.faces.autoCompleteOffOnViewState=true, org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS=com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler, ws.internal.rootPublishedUrl=http://localhost:9000, com.sun.faces.externalizeJavaScript=false, javax.faces.DATETIMECONVERTER_DEFAULT_TIMEZONE_IS_SYSTEM_TIMEZONE=true, javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE=Development, com.sun.faces.preferXHTML=false, javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS=false, javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext=resources.application, contextConfigLocation=classpath*:web-appl-context.xml, javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD=server, com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility=true, com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession=1}
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.cache.lru.LRUMapCacheFactory createCache
INFO: Creating LRUMap cache instance of 512 items capacity
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM org.richfaces.application.InitializationListener onStart
INFO: RichFaces Core Implementation by JBoss, a division of Red Hat, Inc., version v.4.0.0.Final SVN r.22269
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener$WebConfigResourceMonitor$Monitor <init>
INFO: Monitoring jndi:/localhost/Claimer.UI/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml for modifications
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:14 AM com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ELResolverInitPhaseListener populateFacesELResolverForJsp
INFO: JSF1027: [null] The ELResolvers for JSF were not registered with the JSP container.
09:42:15.764 INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor - Outbound Message

Eki 02, 2012 9:42:18 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\conf\Catalina\localhost\insight.xml
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:18 AM com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.ltw.TomcatWeavingInsightClassLoader start
INFO: Context [localhost|insight] will not be woven
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:19 AM com.springsource.insight.InsightAgentPluginsHelper defaultInsightLogs
INFO: Using default insight.logs=C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\insight\logs
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:20 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:50 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\webapps\manager
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Users\osahin\Downloads\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.1.RELEASE\spring-insight-instance\webapps\ROOT
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Eki 02, 2012 9:42:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 106463 ms
```

Comment: How are you accessing mysite:8080/insight  ?  Can you try with firefox ?

Comment: I tried with Firefox too, it doesn't help.

Comment: Any chance you could upload a screenshot of the Browse Resources tab in the Insight UI ?

Comment: I don't have Browse Resources available. [Here](http://i46.tinypic.com/357hevs.jpg) is my screenshot.